# UIApplication not launching to make phone call

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have this code:

```
NSString *telURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:1-%@",((UIButton*) sender).titleLabel.text];
telURL = [telURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telURL]];
```

But it does not launch the dialer application to make a phone call.

I've checked the string telURL and its contents are : "tel:[REDACTED]", which to my understanding is what it needs to be.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
In the event that it matters I've just been running this on the simulator. I won't have a physical device for a few days. (And from the answers  below apparently it does matter)

Comment: I don't think you can make phone calls (without the phone app or contact selector).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You answered your own question. The tel: URL does NOT work on the iPhone simulator AND the iPod Touch (and iPad, of course).  It ONLY works on the iPhone.

Comment: Also you might check the number, I think you are missing a digit at the end. tel:1-717-432-243

Answer (score 3):

That matters. There is no telephone app in the simulator. And trying to open a telephone URL on a device (iPod touch, simulator) that doesn't have the app, just silently fails.

Your formatting is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

First, just checking you are running on hardware that includes a phone (not iPod touch) and not the simulator right? The simulator won't let you test this.

An easy way to get rid of whitespace in your phone number is:

```
NSString *phoneURLString = [[self.phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

Also you should be programmatically checking if the device (or simulator) can handle the url. Simple way to check that is using canOpenURL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourPhoneNumberStringHere]]
```