# How to open mail or dialer in Xamarin.Forms in IOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The below code is working for android only.

Uri t = new Uri("tel:9999999999");
Device.OpenUri(t);

Uri t = new Uri("mailto:phitesh995@gmail.com");
Device.OpenUri(t);

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5640788/1970317

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually i was tested this code in IOS emulator. So afterwards i come to know that my emulator doesnt having mailing as well as calling application. So i tried in iPhone its working properly.